# Can I play a music on Windows 7 and output its sound to both Audio outputs?

Tags: windows-7, audio, music, dell-studio

I have a Dell XPS Studio 16. It has two audio outputs for headphones.

When I play music on Windows 7 using Windows Media Player, it can only listen to one of my two audio outputs (I can only set one as default and not both):

[image]

As seen in this image, each output has its own item called "Speakers".
Can I split the sound to be listen on both Audio output ports?

[image]

Comment: The funny part is that my wife can play a music and listen on both audio ports of Hewlett Packard Pavilion notebook, and she also uses Windows 7 :-/

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need an application that support multiple outputs. Windows 7 only allows sound from 1 output, unless otherwise specified by the program. I do not know of any programs that will manage this, besides Virtual DJ maybe.

Comment: As above. Use to do this back in Windows 98se but needed 3rd party DJ software to do it.

Comment: With that, as far as I can see, 3rd party is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try using each of the audio jacks. If headphones/speakers are plugged into both, then yes, sound will come out of both.